# Users get disconnected from websocket server when other user join the server based on Ratchet

Tags: php, android, websocket, okhttp, ratchet

I am connecting to the websocket from android app with the help of okhttp library. I tried to look for the logs to debug when some user disconnects automatically. The android app (okhttp) shows this log at `onFailure`, that is not enough to debug the code why user get disconnected.

```
onFailure: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
```

This is websocket server code (Ratchet Websocket Library). From android app i can connect with the server but i think there is some issue in this code.

The problem :-

When User A Connect with the server onOpen called that means User A is connected with the websocket server but after few seconds when User B send request to connect to the websocket server, User B get connected and User A onFailure get called and this disconnect User A from websocket server.Can you check if there is any issue with this code? or how i can debug the issue.

```
<?php

require_once("/home/bitnami/vendor/autoload.php");
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

class WebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();

    }
    

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Handle new WebSocket connection
        // You can add the connection to $this->clients for future reference
            
        $request = $conn->httpRequest;
        // Get the action
        $action = $request->getHeaderLine("action");
        // Check if the action is "addClient"
        if ($action === "addClient") {
            // Add the user to the list of connected users
            $userId = $request->getHeaderLine('userId');
            
            // Save the user ID in the resourceId property of the connection
            $conn->resourceId = $userId;
            // Add the connection to the clients list
            $this->clients->attach($conn, $userId);
            
            // Store the connected user in the file
            $connectedUsers = $this->getConnectedUsers();
            $connectedUsers[$userId] = true;
            $this->saveConnectedUsers($connectedUsers);         
                    
        }
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        // Handle incoming WebSocket message
        // You can process the message and send a response back to the client
        
        $data = json_decode($msg, true); // Assuming the message is in JSON format
        file_put_contents('zee.log',print_r($data,true));
                
        
        $myUserID = $data['myID']; // Extract the user ID from the message
        $otherUserID = $data['otherID'];
        //$myFCM = $data['myFCM'];
        
        $isSDP = false;
        $Offer_Answer = $data['offerAnswer'];
        $SDPorICE='';
        if (isset($data['sdp'])) {
        // The 'key' exists in the JSON data
        $SDPorICE = $data['sdp'];
        $isSDP = true;
        } else {
        $SDPorICE = $data['ice'];
        $isSDP = false;
        
        }
        
        if($isSDP){
        $response = [
            'senderUserId' => $myUserID,
            //'senderName' => $myName, // Send Name at last connection message i.e. when sending ICE
            'type' => SDP,
            'offer_answer' => $Offer_Answer,
            'SDP_ICE_info' => $SDPorICE];
        
        }else{
            // If ICE answer then it will not contains image and user name 
            // Check if Offer_Answer is equal to offer
                if ($Offer_Answer === "offer") {
                  // Send the JSON with the sender image and name
                  $response = [
                    'senderUserId' => $myUserID,
                    'type' => ICE,
                    'offer_answer' => $Offer_Answer,
                    'SDP_ICE_info' => $SDPorICE,
                    'senderImage' => $data['myImage'],
                    'senderName' => $data['myName']
                  ];

                } else {

                  // Send the JSON without the sender image and name
                  $response = [
                    'senderUserId' => $myUserID,
                    'type' => ICE,
                    'offer_answer' => $Offer_Answer,
                    'SDP_ICE_info' => $SDPorICE
                  ];

                }
        }

        
        

        // Find the connection of User B in the clients list
        $recipientConnection = $this->findClientConnection($otherUserID);
        if ($recipientConnection !== null) {
            // Send the response message to User B
            $recipientConnection->send(json_encode($response));
        } else {
            // User B is not connected, handle the scenario
            // Other User /The person who is getting call/Receiver 
            
        }
        
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        
        // Remove the disconnected user from the file
        $userId = $conn->resourceId;
        $connectedUsers = $this->getConnectedUsers();
        unset($connectedUsers[$userId]);
        $this->saveConnectedUsers($connectedUsers);

    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        file_put_contents('zee_onError.log',print_r(func_get_args(),true));
        $conn->close();
    }
    
    private function findClientConnection($userId) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client->resourceId === $userId) {
                return $client;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
    
    private function saveConnectedUsers($connectedUsers) {
        $file = 'connected_users.txt';
        $jsonData = json_encode($connectedUsers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents($file, $jsonData);
    }
    
    private function getConnectedUsers() {
    $file = 'connected_users.txt';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $jsonData = file_get_contents($file);
            $connectedUsers = json_decode($jsonData, true);
            return is_array($connectedUsers) ? $connectedUsers : [];
        }

    return [];
    }
    
}
    


    $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new WebSocketHandler()
                )
            ),
            20081
        );


    $server->run();
```

okhttp Singleton Class For Websocket:- This class useful to call when device is in backgroud (User B) without callback and User A with callbacks.

```
public class Websocket {
    private static final String TAG = "###WebSocket###";
    private static final String WEBSOCKET_URL = "wss://example.com:8080";


    private static WebSocket webSocket;

    static WebSocketCallback webSocketCallback;

    public static void connectWebSocket(WebSocketCallback callback) {
        if (callback != null){
            webSocketCallback = callback;
        }
        initWebsocket();
    }

    public static void disconnectWebSocket() {
        if (webSocket != null) {
            webSocket.cancel();
        }
    }

    public static void sendMessage (String msg){
        Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: Message = "+msg);
        if (webSocket == null){
            initWebsocket();
        }
        if (webSocket !=null ){
            webSocket.send(msg);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: Websocket is Null");
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getmContext(), "Unable to connect.Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private static void initWebsocket(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initWebsocket: "+webSocket);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url(WEBSOCKET_URL)
                .addHeader("action", "addClient")
                .addHeader("userId", Session.getUserID())
                .build();
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener);
    }

    private static WebSocketListener webSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClosed(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NonNull String reason) {
            super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
            Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: "+code+" Reason = "+reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NonNull String reason) {
            super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
            // WebSocket connection is closed
            Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: Reason = "+reason);
            if (webSocketCallback != null){
                webSocketCallback.onConnectionClosed(reason);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
            // Handle WebSocket connection failure
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Throwable "+t.getMessage()+" Response == "+response+" User ID = "+Session.getUserID());
            if (webSocketCallback != null){
                webSocketCallback.onConnectionFailure(t.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull String text) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
            // Handle received messages from the WebSocket server
            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Message Received On onMessage = "+text);
            if (webSocketCallback != null){
                webSocketCallback.onConnectionsMessage(text);
            }else {
                try{
                    JSONObject socketMessage = new JSONObject(text);
                    String type = socketMessage.getString("type");
                    String sdp_ice_VALUE = socketMessage.getString("SDP_ICE_info");
                    String offerAnswer = socketMessage.getString("offer_answer");
                    boolean ifcheck  = offerAnswer.equals("offer");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: boolean = "+ifcheck +"------" +type);
                    if (type.equals("SDP")){
                        if (socketMessage.getString("offer_answer").equals("offer")){
                            // Received An SDP Offer From User A
                            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Msg Received 2= "+type);
                            WebRTCUtils.generateAnswerSDP(MyApplication.getmContext(),sdp_ice_VALUE,1);
                        }else {
                            // SAVE remote answer
                        }
                    }else {
                        // Received ICE offer From User A
                        String UserImage = socketMessage.getString("senderImage");
                        String UserName = socketMessage.getString("senderName");
                        WebRTCUtils.getICE_createPeerConnection(MyApplication.getmContext(),4,sdp_ice_VALUE);


                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Error "+e.getMessage());
                }

            }




            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: "+text);

        }



        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Response response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
            // WebSocket connection is successfully established
            Log.d(TAG, "onOpen: User ID = "+Session.getUserID());
            if (webSocketCallback != null){
                webSocketCallback.onConnectionSuccess();
            }else {
                //Calling from Notifications, The On Message will call automatically next because user A sending
                // Message
            }
        }

    };

   

}
```

User A using this fragment class to connect with the websocket.

```
public class ChatScreen extends Fragment {

    OkHttpClient client;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        client = new OkHttpClient();

        FCMToken_Other = getArguments().getString("fcm");


        initializeWebRTC();
        // Set up local video and audio tracks

        setupUI(view);
        generateICE();
        startCall();
    }


   

   
    private void startCall() {
       
       Websocket.connectWebSocket(new WebSocketCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuccess() {
                        //Websocket Connected
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuccess: Websocket Connected");
                        String message = generateJSON(sessionDescription.description,true,"offer");
                        Websocket.sendMessage(message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailure(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailure: Message = "+message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionClosed(String reason) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionClosed: Reason = "+reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionsMessage(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Message = "+message);
                        // Here User will receive the message from the websocket
                        try{
                            JSONObject socketMessage = new JSONObject(message);
                            String type = socketMessage.getString("type");
                            String sdp_ice_VALUE = socketMessage.getString("SDP_ICE_info");
                            if (type.equals("SDP")){
                                SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,sdp_ice_VALUE);
                                peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new com.elaxer.User_Chat_Functionality.Call.SimpleSdpObserver(),sessionDescription);
                                //Generate ICE and Send it User B
                                generateICE();
                            }else {
                                // Received ICE from server as answer, This is the last step in exchanging info
                                WebRTCUtils.addIceCandidate(peerConnection,sdp_ice_VALUE);
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Error "+e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        App_Functions.transparentStatusBar(getActivity(), false, false);
        ((Navigation_Drawer) getActivity()).showBackButton(true);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

       
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Release resources
        if (videoSource != null) {
            videoSource.dispose();
            videoSource = null;
        }
        if (videoCapturer != null) {
            try {
                videoCapturer.stopCapture();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            videoCapturer.dispose();
            videoCapturer = null;
        }
        if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
            peerConnectionFactory.dispose();
            peerConnectionFactory = null;
        }
        if (rootEglBase != null) {
            rootEglBase.release();
            rootEglBase = null;
        }
    }

    private class CustomPeerConnectionObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {
        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
            // Handle signaling state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: "+signalingState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
            // Handle ICE connection state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: "+iceConnectionState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
            // Handle ICE connection receiving change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: "+b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
            // Handle ICE gathering state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: "+iceGatheringState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
            // Handle ICE candidate
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: "+iceCandidate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: "+iceCandidates.length);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            // Handle new stream added
            Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: "+mediaStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            // Handle stream removed
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: "+mediaStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
            // Handle data channel
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: "+dataChannel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
            // Handle renegotiation needed
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {

        }
    }


    // Helper class for handling SDP observer events
    private static class SimpleSdpObserver implements SdpObserver {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: Class Session Description = "+sessionDescription.description);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(String s) {}
    }

    
}
```

Comment: The onFailure message tells you that you use a null pointer. NullPointerException.

Comment: User A and user B? On how many devices? A user will not try to connect but an app on the device the user uses. Please explain your setup.

Comment: @blackapps the error message i am getting at `onFailure` is not saying anything about the why it gets fail. The throwable saying about String, not related to error/issue.

Comment: @blackapps I am just testing it on 2 devices. You might get the idea that by code that i am trying to implement webrtc, so for this i am sending info between User A to User B. As soon as User get connect User B get disconnect without any notice or actual cause just onFailure message on User B device.